# Androidのinit.rcにてスクリプトを実行させたい

Tags: android, iptables

Android(O)の環境にiptablesのシェルスクリプトを置いて
init.rcで実行させるようにしたいです。
以下では効いていませんでした・・・
ご存じの方教えてもらえないでしょうか？
init.rcには以下を追加しています。
ファイルなどは存在しています

```
 on property:sys.boot_completed=1
        exec - root root -- /system/bin/sh /vendor/bin/iptables.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
SELinuxのコンテキストを省略すると実行できていませんでした。
× exec - root root -- /system/bin/sh /vendor/bin/iptables.sh
〇 exec (SELinuxのコンテキスト) root root -- /system/bin/sh /vendor/bin/iptables.sh